AWS patch baseline override
I need to override the default AWS-RunPatchBaseline with RedHatOnprem-Prod if linux and WindowsOnprem-Prod if windows. so I put in an s3 bucket the following json
{
  "Operation": "AWS:PatchManager.OverridePatchBaseline",
  "Parameters": {
    "BaselineId": "",
    "Replace": {
      "Linux": {
        "PatchBaselineId": "RedHatOnprem-Prod"
      },
      "Windows": {
        "PatchBaselineId": "WindowsOnprem-Prod"
      }
    }
  }
}

and configured the s3 url as baseline override, but I get the following error
Invoke-PatchBaselineOperation : The provided BaselineOverride is invalid json{
  "Operation": "AWS:PatchManager.OverridePatchBaseline",
  "Parameters": {
    "BaselineId": "",
    "Replace": {
      "Linux": {
        "PatchBaselineId": "RedHatOnprem-Prod"
      },
      "Windows": {
        "PatchBaselineId": "WindowsOnprem-Prod"
      }
    }
  }
}
At C:\ProgramData\Amazon\SSM\InstanceData\mi-03d22f5a642181636\document\orchestration\4f13d6a6-3136-4f65-b767-342d5669e
4fd\PatchWindows\_script.ps1:204 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-PatchBaselineOperation -Operation Install -Snapsho ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Amazon.Patch.Ba...UpdateOperation:InstallWindowsUpdateOperation) [Inv 
   oke-PatchBaselineOperation], InvalidDataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PatchBaselineOperations,Amazon.Patch.Baseline.Operations.PowerShellCmdlets.InvokePatchBa 
   selineOperation
Exception calling "ToString" with "0" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At C:\ProgramData\Amazon\SSM\InstanceData\mi-03d22f5a642181636\document\orchestration\4f13d6a6-3136-4f65-b767-342d5669e
4fd\PatchWindows\_script.ps1:208 char:5
+     $response.tostring()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
failed to run commands: exit status 0xffffffff

could please someone help me in this?
Thanks
